# How can I get response from loopback in Angular7

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, loopback

I'm using angular7 with loopback. I can get the only data. can anyone tell me how to get the error and response status. I want know what is my response code on request time.

**output of data**

```
[
 {
"name": "karthik",
"lastname": "Selvakumar",
"course": "BE",
"year": "IV"
"id": 2
 }
]
```

Comment: your question is not clear, please provide more details about your issue.

Comment: @AbdelkarimELAMEL Actually i want know my response code in json format.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the reponse code from the HttpResponse like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from  "@angular/common/http";
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  status;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?page=0', {observe: 'response'})
    .toPromise().then((response) => {
      this.status = response.status;
    })
  }
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oq8nid)